# Instantiating a class with an arbitrary number of attributes

Tags: python, class, variables, variable-assignment

This question is specifically in the context of Python classes here, but could be more generalized.  I am creating a class `m` that will be initialized with four variables, which I would then like to assign to the instantiation of the class.  Right now, this looks like this:

```
class mm(object):
  def __init__(self, a, b, c, r):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
    self.r = r
  # etc.
```

However, I would like to be able to assign the variables to `self` in one line, something like the pseudocode:

```
def __init__(self, a, b, c, r):
  self.varname = var for var in [a, b, c, r]
```

It would be even better if this could be generalized to an arbitrary number of variables, so that you could get something like:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
  assign(self, varname, value) for varname, value in kwargs.iteritems()
```

However, as far as I know, it's not really possible to loop through statements like that.  Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: If you really, really wanted to do it in one line, you could use `setattr` in combination with `map` (in your `**kwargs` example, `_ = map(lambda (a, v): setattr(self, str(a), v), kwargs.items())`), but I'd go with the same two-liner from nameless below :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey that's a great one liner.

Comment: @MikeVella Ha, thanks (although for the sake of others reading my code, I'd probably never use it :) ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `setattr`:

```
class mm(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for varname, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, varname, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the instance's namespace dictionary for a mass assignment:

```
class mm(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Comment: You really shouldn't do this. The double underscore is indicating that "__dict__" should be treated as private.

Comment: @MikeVella: Attribute names with double underscores on both sides indicate [special attributes](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), not a private ones. Attribute names with double unserscores on the left side but not the right enforce name mangling. Though such names are considered [private names](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) of the class they're defined in, they're not private in the Java/C++/C# sense.

Comment: @MikeVella: Also, please follow [this link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named) to see who came up with what thikonom showed.

Comment: @pillmuncher fair enough regarding the double underscore on both sides. Though I still think this is a really bad solution for this case - In the code recipe you sent me it's emphasised that this is only reasonable for a trivial "bunch" class.